# Use OpenCV to find breast cage area on mouse x-ray mages

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I`m kind of new in OpenCV. I have a task to automate breast cage area calculation based on mouse x-ray. So now i only have o body contour.

Code i use

```
import cv2 as cv


img = cv.imread("sample.jpg")

gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray_gauss = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (9, 9), 0)

ret, thresh = cv.threshold(gray_gauss, 130, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

contours, _ = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

cv.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 255, 255), 2)

cv.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv.imshow("main", img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is sample image
[mouse x-ray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwzD8.jpg)

The result i have
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMS0U.jpg)

Is any chance i can find only breast cage contour in this image?

Comment: This is really a hard task because the image has low contrast and much noise. That is, you will have to (a) train a model with many sample images where the breast chest area was already detected manually or (b) implement a long sequence of rules that describes how this area can be detected. Which way do you want to go?

Comment: @Markus, second, cuz i don`t have much time and resources for training a model. Can you give me an advice, how can i describe this rules, please?

Comment: As a first step please add an image to your question where you manually outline the area you want to detect. Then add a second image where you mark those points of the skeleton that you think are essential for autmatically recognizing this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go the tedious classic path, I would try finding rules step by step:

1. Find the basic contours of the body.
2. Find the legs.
3. Estimate rectangular region around the chest by normal mouse proportions.
4. Find landmarks in this region that can be used to outline the chest.

If you find that the quality of the input image is too low and even a human being has to guess the area or estimate its position by experience then you will have to define rules for guessing, too.

It's nearly impossible to find adequate rules from only one image and without human experience. This is why training a model with many examples and input from experts often is more reliable.